# Actions on Google link third party service account using non-GoogleAssistant integration

Tags: authorization, telegram, actions-on-google

I am working on Google Action for smart devices and using Dialogflow interaction schema with Java fulfillment. Fulfillment should call third party API to complete requests. For the purpose of the task, I must use a custom OAuth server. According to docs, I filled Action Account Linking information in Action Console with Grant Type: Authorization Code. For all intents including Welcome "Sign in required" is set.
When testing with Google Home device or Google Home surface in Simulator menu, I get clear message "*It looks like your Demo Service account is not linked yet. You can link Demo Service to your Google Account from the Google Home app.*" And as expected I get Linking Card in Google Home App to login and get AccessToken for third party service. Everything is OK here.
But when using Telegram integration or Phone surface in Simulator I just get "*It looks like your Demo Service account is not linked yet*" and nothing happen neither in Telegram, nor in Google Home App. How should user authentication for third party service be managed in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Actions on Google simulator, when you get the *"It looks like your Demo Service account is not linked yet"* you can achieve account linking by clicking on the DEBUG tab then open in a browser the url in *"debugInfo"*. (See below)

[image]

The Phone surface simulates the Google Assistant app on Android or iOS devices. Users on these platforms will be prompted directly for account linking. (See below image)

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Nazeem. Thank you for quick answer. I try to use link from _DebugInfo_ with my custom OAuth server and on another project with OAuth which belongs to service provider. In both tests looks like authentication works fine and eventually I get redirected to _https://www.google.com/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked_ 
 But I still get "_It looks like your Demo Service account is not linked yet_" when get back to Action testing. I thought new AccessToken should be passed to action. (It is so, if use _DebugInfo_ with _GoogleHome_ simulation)

Comment: Could you test in an incognito tab?

Comment: Wow! It works. I tested on two different PCs with the same failures, but incognito tab do the job(and different browser as well). Thank you very much again!

Comment: Cool! The issue seems to be occurring when you have more than one account on Chrome and the account your testing on isn't the Default one.